# Custom menu GUI

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, tkinter, python-3

I am trying to make a retro gaming console with the Pi Zero W. The first thing I want to happen is a custom menu screen show up. I know how to make a custom Tkinter GUI but I want it to show up when the desktop would usually load up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit), .xinitrc in your home directory will be read and executed.

Otherwise, you can place your script under /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc (I don't know what OS are you using). So, both ways are supposed to run the script when X server starts (again, don't know what OS you're using)

Comment: I'm using the regular version of Rasbian.